# View Contextual filter for content updated dates

Tags: views

I am new to Drupal.

I want to implement a contextual filter in YYYYMMDD or in Unix date format. if I pass a value as 1st Dec 2013 (20131201) then it should return me all the contents who has been updated after that date. I am not able to get how to do it.. I got to know about updated date but its in the format of CCYYMMDD is it same as YYYYMMDD? if not then can I change it to so?

Answer (score 0):

The date format CCYYMMDD is indeed the same YYYYMMDD.

CC means century number as a 2 digit cardinal number where the first century was given the number 00. The present century is century number 20.

YY or YYYY means year (written as a 2 or 4 digit cardinal number with a leading zero if required), The present year is 14 (two digits) or 2014 (four digits).

MM means month as a two digit cardinal number with a leading zero if required.  The present month, January, is written as 01.

DD means day om the month as a two digit cardinal number with a two digit leading zero if required.  Today is day number 24 of January.

In other words, today's date (January 24th 2014) is written `20140124` in both these formats, and December 1st 2013 is written as `20131201` in both these formats.